# Toolbar is a bit out of the screen

Tags: feature-request, bug, android-app

[image: !]

The **More** button is out of the screen, some of it is cut off.

Using Android Xperia M app version 1.0.54

I suggest replacing the toolbar with a scrolling bar (like swipe from right to left for more options) which can fix this problem and can remove the More button which only consists of the buttons **flag** and **open in browser**.

Comment: I don't observe the issue on Nexus 5, but I understand this issue affects on devices with not-so-big screen resolution (talking about the many flavor of Android specs...), so +1.